# Select in where clause, access to current parent select columns

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I have a query which contains a `select` statement in it's where clause. My question is now, how can I access the parent's `select`'s data.

Example:

```
select * from TABLE_1 as t1 INNER JOIN TABLE_2 as t2
where (... and ...) OR 
      (not exists(select * from TABLE_3 as t3 
                                inner join TABLE_1 ON t3.t1_id = t1.id
```

The last line is where the error occurs: `t1.id is not a column`.

How can I access the current value from the table t1?
I'm using MySql 5.1

Comment: Can you post your complete query?

Comment: You need to have the inner table_1 as t4 and have the following condition ON t3.t1_id = t4.id where t4.id = t1.id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  TABLE_1 as t1 
  INNER JOIN TABLE_2 as t2 ON
    t2.PK = t1.FK --Whatever your keys are
WHERE
  (... and ...)
  OR
  (
  NOT EXISTS (select * from TABLE_3 as t3 WHERE t3.t1_id = t1.id)
  )
```

Comment: I added an ON clause to your JOIN to TABLE_2, as it was missing from your example. The solution for you was that your correlated subquery that checks the existence of the row in TABLE_3 was not written properly. Instead of trying to JOIN back to TABLE_1, you just use the column via the t1 alias.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to declare what you will `JOIN` TABLE_2 on TABLE_1.

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE_1 AS t1 
INNER JOIN TABLE_2 AS t2 ON t2.t1_id = t1.id
```

`t1.id = t2.t1_id` is just an example, you will need to decide which columns you wish you join on. Then in your `WHERE` clause, you do not need to `INNER JOIN` on TABLE_1 again as you are already selecting from it.

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE_1 AS t1 
INNER JOIN TABLE_2 AS t2 ON t2.t1_id = t1.id
WHERE (... AND ...) OR 
(
    NOT EXISTS
    (
        SELECT * 
        FROM TABLE_3 AS t3 
        WHERE t3.t1_id = t1.id
    )
)
```